# What could explain unknown I/O on new 16TB HDD on a Debian server?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, io, hdd

I recently obtained a new 16TB HDD for my Debian server.
I first created a partition (gpt) on it via my Ubuntu-like desktop, formatted it (ext4), and rsync'ed old data on it. The disk is now usable, so I insert it into my server.
Now begins a weird I/O that I can't identify.

- `iotop -ao` reports a 3MB/s `Current DISK WRITE` *without any indication* as to who is doing it
- `fatrace -c -t` reports no writing or reading, but do report it if I myself `touch` a file for instance.
- `dstat -tdD /dev/sdx --top-io` reports a steady 3072k write each second as well, consistent with `iotop`, but no culprit either, only a blank in `i/o process` where there should be a name, but it does confirm that the I/O action is on the said disk, which I initially  deduced from the noise it was emitting...

Now I know that there might be inconsistencies between what the iotop header shows and the sum of I/O writes and/or reads from processes as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248197/iotop-showing-1-5-mb-s-of-disk-write-but-all-programs-have-0-00-b-s). But contrary to the previous post, at that time:

- the server was cut off from the internet
- local network was only the server
- I was not performing *any* action on the disk
- I manually exited every program that could use that disk

A couple of hours after (at least 10, no more than 20) the noise was gone, and no more 3MB/s input on the disk.

My question is : could it be normal behavior (though I never observed it before now) (from perhaps the kernel?) to write some caching system, init tables or something similar that could explain this constant 3MB/s write for 10-20 hours?

I initially thought of a crypto/random virus but even 20 hours at 3MB/s could not possibly cover the 12TB written on the 16 available.

Is there any logical explanation for this?

Comment: It's normal, your harddisk is still in the process of being formatted. It's being formatted step-by-step to reduce load on the drive and make it instantly available to your system. Beside a bit decreased performance for now, it will be finished in a week or so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if you fully read my question you'll see that 1) it stopped max 20 hours after it started, and 2) I waited for each action before doing the next, ie I waited for the GPT table to be created to format the disk, I then waited for the end of the formatting to rsync data on it, and the end of rsync to dismount it from the desktop and mount it to the server. I apologize however if by some weird process, the server is able to complete the formatting to some 200Go (3Mb/s for 20 hours) sectors that the desktop might have forgotten about.

Comment: The formatting was/is still ongoing. Inodes must be registered, these are the writes. Don't worry. If you want to know more, read about how the filesystem formatting works. As far as I remember EXT4 should have some worker system service, other filesystems like BTRFS do it internally.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The background IO load you noticed is due to ext4 deferred inode table allocation. From [`mke2fs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mke2fs.8.html) man page:

```
lazy_itable_init[= <0 to disable, 1 to enable>]
    If enabled and the uninit_bg feature is
    enabled, the inode table will not be fully
    initialized by mke2fs.  This speeds up file
    system initialization noticeably, but it
    requires the kernel to finish initializing the
    file system in the background when the file
    system is first mounted.  If the option value
    is omitted, it defaults to 1 to enable lazy
    inode table zeroing.
```

Comment: Definitely this, yes. I looked for such a call in the app I used to format the disk, which is the gnome `disk` app, and there is as of today [an open issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-disk-utility/-/issues/48) to allow using or not this lazy init option.

Answer (score 3):

The kernel or file system might be performing maintenance tasks, such as updating metadata or journaling, which could result in sustained disk writes. These tasks are typically performed in the background to optimize disk performance.

Comment: That was a theory indeed, but then I should at least see a kworker/journald/... on the job or something related, should I not ? Is there a known debian event that does not include a known process (or at least, that iotop/dstat do not known about) that could explain the writes ?

Comment: caching, filesystem operations, or kernel threads handling low-level I/O, may not be explicitly tied to a user-visible process